# change file names inside a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to change all file names inside my directory from name.sql to tbl_name.sql  for example:

> city.sql -> tbl_city.sql or  usr_station.sql -> tbl_usr_staion.sql

could you tell me why the following code snippet is not right please.

```
for file in *.sql
do
  echo $file
  fnew = 'tbl_${file}.sql'
  eval mv ${file} ${fnew}
done
```

Comment: You don't need the `eval` command, just use `mv "$file" "$fnew"`

Answer (score 2):

Following these steps should make the script work:

1. Remove `eval` and using just plain `mv` commands (try to avoid `eval` whenever possible, because it's considered a bad practice and can lead to some serious security issues).
2. Remove the trailing spaces between the `fnew`, the `=` and the string value.
3. Replace the quotes `'` with double quotes `"` so the `$file` is evaluated inside the `fnew` assignation expression .

```bash
for file in *.sql
do
   echo $file
   fnew="tbl_${file}"
   mv "$file" "$fnew"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
for file in *.sql; do mv "$file" tbl_"$file"; done
```

Please note, that in the mv destination there is no additional .sql suffix. It is already contained in the $file variable.